# Python assert statement trigger SystemError: \loewis\release\python\Objects\longobject.c:270: bad argument to internal function

Tags: python, exception, assert, system-error

I have an assert statement in Python that triggers the following exception:

```
SystemError: \loewis\release\python\Objects\longobject.c:270: bad argument to internal function
```

I searched the Python code for the version I'm using (2.4.2) and can see that this error comes from the following function in longobject.c:

```
unsigned long
PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(PyObject *vv)
```

Now I searched this function in Python's source code but I cannot make the link between this function and the Python assert statement.

Do you have any idea where PyLong_AsUnsignedLong is called when calling the Python assert statement?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

PyLong_AsUnsignedLong is from the [C-API Long Integer Object](http://docs.python.org/c-api/long.html).  It returns the C unsigned Long represented of the Python Object passed.

Comment: Hey Abhijit do you know how this relates to Python's assert statement? Thanks!